# How to use Property Transfer to pass refresh_token from Response to request with concatenation : TestSuite soapui

Tags: rest, soapui, jsonpath

[image: when i use jsonPath to get value of refresh token + concatenation with grant_type=refresh_token, the result was only the value of toke]

When i use jsonPath to get value of refresh token + concatenation with grant_type=refresh_token, the result was only the value of token

My source is a POST request. This POST request returns me a JSON. I need to pass the value of refresh_token with grant-type=refresh_token to the next POST request.

Answer (score 2):

The [expression in your Target box](https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/properties/transferring-properties.html) needs to be an XPath or JsonPath expression of where you'd like the property to end up in your next request. I don't know the shape of your messages, so one possible solution is to create, say, a Test Case property called `refresh_token` and transfer the value of your token there:

[image]

Then, in your next request, you could use this property with your concatenation string like this:

```
${= 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=' + context.expand( '${#TestCase#refresh_token}'}
```